# The expected value of the greater and smaller of the two rolls of a die

Tags: probability, expectation, dice

Rolling two four-sided (tetrahedron) dice, what is the expected value of the higher and of the smaller of the two numbers shown?

Partial Solution:
$$EX = 1 \cdot 1/16 + 2\cdot 3/16 +3\cdot 5/16 +4 \cdot7/16 =3.215$$ This will be the expectation of the higher number. But I don't know how to find the expectation of the smaller number.

Comment: $E(\min) = 1\cdot\frac{7}{16} + 2\cdot\frac{5}{16} + 3\cdot\frac{3}{16} + 4\cdot\frac{1}{16} = 1.875$. $E(\max) = 1\cdot\frac{1}{16} + 2\cdot\frac{3}{16} + 3\cdot\frac{5}{16} + 4\cdot\frac{7}{16} = 3.125$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

The expectation of the sum of higher and smaller number is $2\times\frac52$ (do you understand why?).

Also this expectation is the sum of their expectations by linearity of expectations.

So finding one of them is enough.

---

**addendum**:

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ denote the two scores and let $H$ and $S$ denote the highest and smallest score respectively. Then: $$D_1+D_2=H+S$$ so that $$\mathbb ED_1+\mathbb ED_2=\mathbb E(D_1+D_2)=\mathbb E(H+S)=\mathbb EH+\mathbb ES$$

It is not difficult to find that $\mathbb ED_i=\frac52$ so we end up with $$\mathbb EH+\mathbb ES=5$$

Comment: Oh okay, I see how can that can help but I don't understand why

Comment: I have added some explanation.